# SQL query for adding MSSQL Layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, sql-server

I want to add a mssql layer with a SQL query.
It was no problem to do it for PostgreSQL but have somebody an idea of how it is working with the mssql database?

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(host, ort, database, user, password)
uri.setDataSource("","(SELECT distinct  ID FROM Mapdata)","THE_GEOM", "","ID")
vectorlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "MAP_LAYER", "mssql")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vectorlayer, True)
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: it is a SQL Server

Comment: Your title says "MSSQL" but the body says MySQL *twice*. Please [Edit] the question to specify the right product.